# Recordset in excel vba returns nothing while data is present in Access DB

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, eof

I am running my VBA code in excel that connects and extract a recordset from Access. I have a query that makes the selection based on date and an ID. I know the record is present in the table but it seems like when I add my date condition, the recordset is coming out empty.

I have browsed through this website and every suggestion that I have seen, I have tried but still my recordset comes out empty

Here is the code that I am using:

```
'Here is the query

currentday = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
extrct = "select * from Table1 where badge_ID=" & Me.BadgeInput & " " & "and date_pres=" & "#" & currentday & "#"
conn.Open (strconn)

rs3.Open extrct, conn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

'This is where I check for any value is the recordset
If rs3.EOF And rs3.BOF Then -- This is coming out as True (no record)
GoTo 1
Else
GoTo 2
End If
```

I think the date condition has something wrong going on but I can't figure out what considering that I have tried everything I know

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: How is your date stored? If is in date time, and has a time value... it won't be equal. Try `>=`, i.e.:  `..."and date_pres >= " & "#" & currentday & "#"....`

Comment: Use a `Command` with an actual `Date` parameter instead of concatenating the value into the query. That way you don't have to deal with the utter minefield that is working with dates represented as strings.

Comment: Did you try removing the date and leave just badge_ID? that should return records, if that doesn't work, it's not the date. You can also try `CDate(Format(Date, "m/d/yyyy"))` which is one of the most accepted date formats in databases. The format you are using is also accepted but I doesn't hurt to try another. Try `extrct = "SELECT * FROM [Table1] WHERE [badge_ID] = " & Me.BadgeInput & " AND [date_pres] = #" & CDate(Format(Date, "m/d/yyyy")) & "#"`

Comment: Make sure the SQL you produce works in Access as a query. If you can get it working in Access, getting it to work in Excel will be a snap.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I am in europe so the time difference is on! My Date in Access is stored as Date/Time type and has date value in it. I tried removing the date and just leave the Badge_ID and then I got something, that's how I know that my date condition is wrong somewhere. I have tried the suggestions that you proposed (Cdate, date(),...) but still nothing in my recordset. @MathieuGuindon, can you be more specific on your solution?

Comment: Just add after `extrct = ...` a line with following code `Debug.Print extrct` and study results in Immediate pane (Ctrl+G), try this SQL text in query designer

Comment: I have just debugged the sql and used the same sql in Access and there was no output. So what I did is build a query in Access that was giving a result and paste the query in my vba code. Here is the query `extrct = "select * from Table1 where (((Badge_ID)=" & Me.BadgeInput & ") AND ((date_prest)=#" & currentday & "#));"`. This is still giving no result in my recordset. I'm quite lost here!

Comment: I have just noticed when debugging that no matter what `Badge_ID` I insert without specifying the date, the vba is always outputing the first row of the table. How is this possible? Looks like the filtering isn't working as expected. Here is the debug that I have used `For i = 0 To rs3.Fields.Count - 1
Debug.Print rs3(i).Name & vbTab;
Next i
'Debug.Print rs3(rs3.Fields.Count - 1)

Do While Not rs3.EOF
 For i = 0 To rs3.Fields.Count - 1
    Debug.Print rs(i) & vbTab;
 Next i
 Debug.Print rs3(rs3.Fields.Count - 1)
 rs3.MoveNext
Loop`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you live in Europe, it is mandatory to use a correct format for date value expressions:

```
currentday = Format(Date, "yyyy\/mm\/dd")
```

If you this is not just an example, and you will always use today's date, simply use:

```
extrct = "select * from Table1 where badge_ID = " & Me.BadgeInput & " and date_pres = Date()"
```

If you have stored a time component:

```
extrct = "select * from Table1 where badge_ID = " & Me.BadgeInput & " and Fix(date_pres) = Date()"
```

Comment: I have tried changing to this format as well, but still no result in my recordset. This how I defined my variable `currentday = CDate(Format(Date, "yyyy\/mm\/dd")`. I don't understand how I am able to get result when the query is run on Access but nothing when it is run in vba :s

Comment: No, that won't work - and actually doesn't make sense, if you think about it. Use my code line _as is_. Or use my alternative. See edited answer, please.

Comment: Thanks Gustav for your reply. I tried the edited version of your code but still didn't work. After debugging, I don't think the problem lies with the date. In my Access table, I have 11 rows of data. I have run the query without the date condition and changed the value of `BadgeInpu` with 4 existing ones. No matter the value of `BadgeInput`, the recordset always returns the first row of the table. So my guess is the problem lies here, rather than in the date condition. Would you happen to know what is going on here? I have put the debugging code in the comment above. Thanks

Comment: The only thing I can think of is, if the stored dates could have a time part. If so, round this off. See edited answer, please.

Comment: It worked with your third code... amazing! Thanks a lot for your help, very much appreciated :)